# Изображение сохраняется в низком качестве Telegram API

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

У меня проблема я пишу бота на JS Tg API, и у меня при сохранении изображения оно сохраняется в низком качестве.
Вот код

```
tbot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    const chatIdentifier = msg.chat.id;

    // Проверяем, является ли это текстовым сообщением
    if (msg.text) {
        console.log(`<M>${chatIdentifier}:${msg.text}\r\n`);
    }

    // Проверяем, является ли это фотографией
    if (msg.photo) {
        // Получаем информацию о фотографии
        const photo = msg.photo[0];
        const fileId = photo.file_id;

        // Создаем папку для сохранения изображений (если не существует)
        const chatImagesDir = path.join(__dirname, 'data', 'images', 'Chats', `${chatIdentifier}`);
        if (!fs.existsSync(chatImagesDir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(chatImagesDir, { recursive: true });
        }

        // Получаем информацию о файле
        const fileInfo = await bot.getFile(fileId);

        // Получаем ссылку на файл
        const fileLink = `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot${token}/${fileInfo.file_path}`;

        // Определяем путь для сохранения файла
        const filePath = path.join(chatImagesDir, `${Date.now()}_1.jpg`);

        // Получаем более высокое разрешение изображения
        const highResFileLink = `${fileLink}?file_id=${fileId}`;
        const highResResponse = await axios.get(highResFileLink, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, Buffer.from(highResResponse.data));

        console.log(`<Photo saved>${chatIdentifier}:${filePath}\r\n`);
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIxoY.png)

Кто знает в чём проблема?

Пробовал переписывать и менять загрузчик, по разному загружать фото и искал ответы но ничего :(

Comment: А вы выбираете в максимальном разрешении? ТГ же хранит фото в трех вариантах

Comment: _А вы выбираете в максимальном разрешении? ТГ же хранит фото в трех вариантах_

Ааа как это сделать?

Comment: как-то в сторону этого photo[img.photo.length-1].file_id. Я не очень силен в js, но в общем случае: тг возвращает массив фото, и последний объект этого массива и есть оригинал фото. Нужно указать длину массива минус 1, потому что считать начинаем с 0